# Cassandra mistakenly thinks it is running as root

Tags: cassandra, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run Cassandra on a MyBinder environment.
Locally it works just fine. On MyBinder, however, Cassandra  mistakenly thinks it is running as root.

It is has the same java version, OS, etc.

Any ideas on why such behavior?

Thanks!

```sh
jovyan@jupyter-2dx66bgrd2:~$ tar xzvf apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1-bin.tar.gz 

joyan@jupyter-2dx66bgrd2:~$ cd apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1

jovyan@jupyter-2dx66bgrd2:~/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1$ ls
bin  CASSANDRA-14092.txt  CHANGES.txt  conf  doc  lib  LICENSE.txt  NEWS.txt  NOTICE.txt  pylib  tools

jovyan@jupyter-2dx66bgrd2:~/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1$ ./bin/cassandra
Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.
If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option.

jovyan@jupyter-2dx66bgrd2:~/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1$ ./bin/cassandra -R
jovyan@jupyter-2dx66bgrd2:~/apache-cassandra-4.0-beta1$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the startup script thinks it's being run as a `root` user when running `id -u` or `id -g` in `bin/cassandra` ([here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0-beta1/bin/cassandra#L274-L278)):

```
if [ "`id -u`" = "0" ] || [ "`id -g`" = "0" ] ; then
    echo "Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user."
    echo "If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option."
    exit 1
fi
```

I suppose the `id` commands return `0` in MyBinder and confuses the startup script. This isn't a scenario we test so perhaps workaround it by disabling the check in the shell script. Cheers!

Comment: I am glad you answered. Sadly, It did not work. Now the scripts fails after a ".../apache-cassandra-3.11.7/logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory". I created the folder, it creates the file (empty) and crashes without any further information =(

This is the [link to mybinder](https://gke.mybinder.org/v2/gh/thedatasociety/lab-cassandra/master?urlpath=lab) with everything already downloaded and configured in the path. It works just perfectly locally, but not in mybinder. 
Thanks heaps, @flightc. Please let me know if you have suggestion. I am really lost here

Comment: Found the solution. Just had to adjust Java heap sizes to fit MyBinder restrictions. Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out. Cheers!